# where is git init in atom?

Tags: git, github

After I install the plugin "git-plus"in atom, I can not find the 'git:plus init' ,why?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure of git-plus. Just do a git init from your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

git-plus as far as I am aware does not have an `init` command. As suggested in the comments the simplest way would be to just open up a terminal change in to your project directory and run `git init`. Alternatively you could install one of the many terminal packages for atom and run the command from the terminal within atom. After you have run `git init` `git-plus` should have all that you need.